# Outputting text to a Windows Form periodically - speed issues

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a fairly intensive application, which I've just converted from a console application to a Windows Form application. The program essentially loops through a couple of thousand of customers, and creates invoices based upon their deliveries. For every delivery, and customer, information would be output to the console window - which means there's a lot of information being output! The old process took up to 20 mintues, which was reasonable given the scale of what it was doing. But my manager, and the customer, wants it as a Windows Form now.

I've implemented this, and to output the information I cheated a bit and simply replaced all Console.WriteLine() calls in the existing code to call a method of mine, which *appends* the given text to a TextBox on the Windows Form.

I've had 2 problems with this:

1: The textbox will occasionally 'freeze' and go white - but I assume I can't use more than 1 thread, because I'll be periodically calling the textbox on a different thread

2: More seriously, the 20 minute process of before now takes significantly longer - around 4-5 hours. I'm certain that the dataset hasn't been enlarged dramatically, as to test all code we roll back to an old position, and the only issue i can think of is me appending to a textbox. I'll be testing without any textbox writes tomorrow to confirm this, but the code hasn't changed in any other way

Is there any other, easier methods to output text to a Windows Form, multiple times a second?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your best bet here is to NOT output all of the data straight into a text box.

Instead spin up a second thread to handle the processing.  Every so often (20 records? 100?) sync that thread with the main one to update some type of progress bar.

Have the thread write the normal text updates to either a database or a text file.

Once it has completed, load that text file and display to the user.

Nearly all of the extra time is spent with the application's main thread redrawing the form; which is an expensive process.  When it does this the processing is basically blocked (same thread).  Because the amount of data in the textbox grows, the amount of time it spends doing the update increases linearly with each append to your textbox... So, 10 records won't notice much of an impact.  1000+ will.. depending on how much data you are appending.

Comment: Thanks for the great advice. I've decided to change my code to open a Console window, where the text will be output to, as well as stored in a StringBuilder to store in a log.

Answer (score 1):

I *would* suggest using a worker thread, and making thread safe callbacks to update the text area.

Microsoft provides an example of this here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx

The other thing you're likely running into is a lot of overhead with the system re-creating the string in the text box every time it updates.  You'll want to limit how often you do that or the UI won't be able to keep up.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of problems:

1. Windows Forms has thread affinity.  This means all writes have to happen on the UI thread.  If you're working with multiple threads, make sure to marshal the calls back to the main thread with `Control.Invoke` or `Control.BeginInvoke`.
2. Appending to the string in the TextBox is going to get progressively slower and slower as the text gets larger.  Try reducing the number of appends you make.

Personally, I would suggest trying the following:

Use a `BackgroundWorker` to run your operation.  You can maintain a `textToAppend` variable of type `StringBuilder` that allows you to append your text.  At regular intervals (ie: in the progress changed handler, perhaps), append the entire block of text to your `TextBox` (or `RichTextBox`) control.  You will likely need to synchronize access to the string builder, via a lock or other mechanism, to prevent a race condition from occurring.

This will do two things.  First, it'll *dramatically* reduce the number of string concatenation operations.  This will probably get you back a large portion of that lost speed.  It will also keep your UI responsive as the operation runs, since the process will execute in a background thread.